# Print Enum value in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, enums, jpanel, jtextfield

How would I get a JTextField to show the string of a Enum status. For example I want to call an Enum and have the JTextField show its current state, such as WON or LOST.

The bottom one is the one I am trying to get.

```
          die1.setText(Integer.toString(craps.die1));
          die2.setText(Integer.toString(craps.die2));
          sum.setText(Integer.toString(craps.sum));
          point.setText(Integer.toString(craps.point));
          status.setText();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please tell us the details, where you're stuck, why you can't just set the text with the correct enum. There's more to your problem than what you're telling us. Consider posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a enum like

```
enum Status{
    WON,
    LOSS
}
```

Than print like below using `name` method on `JTextField`.

```
Status gameStatus=getGameStatus();// Get the game status 
switch(gameStatus){
    case WON:
       status.setText(Status.WON.name());
       break;
     .... similar for all status.
   }
```

Comment: The Enum changes, so I want it to show the current Enum state, not a predefined one.

Comment: Than, use switch or if-else statement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Ah, got it, thanks. I was not familiar with that method!